# Exploit stdin to call local function in C

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

Note: this is extra credit for a homework assignment

I'm trying to figure out how to call `win()` via `stdin`. I assumed that the vulnerability would be exploited by a buffer overflow, but I can't even figure out how to overflow the buffer (if I input a 45-character string, it prints all 45 characters). What sort of vulnerability should I be looking for here, and how would I go about exploiting it?

```
int win()
{
    printf("Great Job\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[40];
    unsigned long long target;

    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("You sent: %s\n", buffer);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You are indeed overflowing the buffer if you are able to store 45 bytes where there is only space for 40, no? Is this really all of the code? Seems odd that `target` is defined but not used. As is, you could maybe leak some addresses, but after a quick look, I don't see a way to hijack execution flow as it stands (due to the `exit()`).

Comment: @multithr3at3d yep, this is all the code provided. I've been trying to overwrite the eip for the better part of 2 days now with no luck. If I understand the layout correctly, 40 characters fills the buffer, another 4 overwrites the ebp, and the next 4 will overwrite the eip. However, nothing I do manages to touch the value in eip. I can change the ebp with ease, but the eip doesn't budge. so I think you're right, there doesn't seem to be a way.

Comment: Keep in mind that you actually aren't overflowing into any of those registers until they are actually popped off the stack during leave/return. Problem is, you never reach the return of main because of `exit()`.